# How to use rust opencv to pass a complete parameter to set_mouse_callback

Tags: opencv, rust, closures, lifetime

I'm trying to do something with Rust's binding [opencv](https://github.com/twistedfall/opencv-rust), and the general idea is to capture the image block in the corresponding position based on mouse press and release. I mainly refer to the [Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60610097), one of the [`cv.line`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) by [`cv.rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) alternative to satisfy my needs. But I ran into some problems when I tried writing in Rust again. My code is as follows:

```
use opencv::{highgui, imgcodecs, Result};

struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}
impl Point {
    fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Self {
        Self { x, y }
    }
}
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let img_path = "./1.jpg";
    let img = imgcodecs::imread(img_path, imgcodecs::IMREAD_COLOR)?;
    
    highgui::named_window("image", 0)?;
    highgui::set_window_property(
        "image",
        highgui::WINDOW_NORMAL,
        highgui::WND_PROP_VISIBLE.into(),
    )?;
    
    // To store mouse positions when click and release
    let mut pos: [Point; 2];
    highgui::set_mouse_callback(
        "image",
        Some(Box::new(
            |event: i32, x: i32, y: i32, _flags: i32| match event {
                highgui::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN => pos = [Point::new(x, y),Point::new(x, y)], // borrowed value does not live long enough
                highgui::EVENT_LBUTTONUP => pos[1] = todo!(),   
                _ => (),
            },
        )),
    )?;

    let mut key: i32;
    loop {
        highgui::imshow("image", &img)?;
        key = highgui::wait_key(1)?;
        if key == b'q'.into() {
            println!("Exit successfully.");
            break;
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

I'm not sure if I wrote [`set_mouse_callback`](https://docs.rs/opencv/latest/opencv/highgui/fn.set_mouse_callback.html) correctly because the current way I write it prevents me from moving the `pos` variable into a closure. I guess this is because I have a problem passing parameters inside the closure. I'm new to Rust and would love to talk to you about it. Thank you.

The lifetimes of `pos` in a closure is not long enough. I want to modify the value of `pos` within the closure so that I can use the `pos` variable later.

Comment: You need shared ownership, see [Need holistic explanation about Rust's cell and reference counted types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674479/need-holistic-explanation-about-rusts-cell-and-reference-counted-types)